# angular version 4 http sends number as string

Tags: javascript, angular, swagger

I use angular 4.4.6 and I want to send a http request to swagger-enabled endpoint. I want to send a number there, but it always being sent as a string.

```
approve(id1: number){

 .....

let params={id:id1}

return this.http.post(approveUrl, params)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

But I want to send number, not string, not anything else.

In my swagger:

```
        parameters:
          - name: body
            schema:
              required:
                - id
              properties:
                id:
                  description: Priority order
                  type: number
                  format: int32
            in: body
            required: true
```

I always get 400 (Bad request) except one case: {id: 5}, where 5- any hardcoded number.

How to create a simple and bulletproof solution to send number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to convert it to number :

```
let params={id:+id1}
```